# How to run an executable file in Debian 10?

Tags: linux, cron, systemd, systemctl

I have an executable file say `myserver`. I always run it by appending `./` infront of file name in debian 10 terminal. e.g. `./myserver`. I am wondering if there are other ways to execute/run this file apart from using `./`.

Note: `file` commands shows the following information about my file.

```
file myserver
myserver: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=82wr8_Xx7EP7lh6rXfs4/w6MXLU_08grWoInEvoEg/im3xy25cSUGiNkWCWC6M/1IjwBIGip3ebxtcXy09u, stripped
```

I want to run this file automatically at boot since i am tired of typing `./myserver` in the terminal every times my machine reboots. Since it is binary file and not a service, so i setup a system service using `systemd` with the following contents.

```
[Unit]
Description=myserver
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=./myserver
WorkingDirectory=/home/sahar
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=sahar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However i am getting the following error.

```
● myserver.service - myserver
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit myserver.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/myserver.service:6: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ./myserver
systemd[1]: myserver.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
```

Does this error means I can not execute the file now using `./`? I have tried it with `bash myserver` and `sh myserver` but no luck.

Any solution is appreciated.

Regards,
Sahar

Answer (score 0):

In Linux . refers to the current directory you are working in. `./name_of_some_program` gives the **relative** path to that program. You can check your current/present working directory with `pwd` command.

If your current working directory is /home/machine and you have a file in that directory you wanna execute. Let the name of that file be A. You give the path of that file to shell. You can either do `./A` or `/home/machine/A`. The latter is called absolute path.

So, in `systemd` service file you need to mention absolute path not relative.
Give the value of absolute path to `Execstart` key.

Comment: Thanks @sam for your response. I replaced `ExecStart=./myserver` with `ExecStart=/home/sahar/myserver`. Now i can start this service using command `systemctl start myserver.service`. I have enabled this service to run at boot using the following commands `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` `sudo systemctl start myserver.service` `sudo systemctl enable myserver.service`.
However the service **does not** start itself on boot.  I am stuck due to my limited knowledge of linux.

Comment: What was the status of service after rebooting.
Check out logs using journalctl command.